# Android WebView Add Custom HTTP Header to each response

Tags: android, webview, http-headers, addition

I understand that you can override Android WebView functionality using the *WebViewClient* and have been successfully implemented in many areas. The overrides do not give access to the request object.

The iPhone UIWebView has a very powerful way to control each request object. Is there a another way to do this in Android WebView?

Even if you use the *loadUrl* function with to add a custom header, it does not get added to subsequent requests. I have seen a lot of responses in other questions, but they are not satisfactory.

Can anyone please provide some insight into how to implement this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you probably already know. After Android 18, you can "add" headers. Otherwise you can change the user-agent. I looked in the WebView source code.  Four objects deep in the code is a WebViewFrame object with this call:

```
private native void nativeLoadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> headers);
```

So deeper down in C code is the loading of the headers that Google wants to shove down our throats. We can now add new ones but are stuck with their choices otherwise. "Open Source" means "Donating Your Work to Corporate Profits" apparently. There's a reason they chose the Apache license over the GNU GPL.  But I digress.

Bottom line is, as we said in the Army, that we are SOL here Android-wise. So here's a thought:

Don't use loadUrl. Maybe you can write your own loadPage and just use Java to make the call and then use the webview to load the response as data. Probably have to add a jar file to the app for anything Android has tried to cut out of Java. I'm going try this.